# How to generate treads and risers over a line with variable slope length, height, and angle?

Tags: c#

I am trying to basically create a series of treads (horizontal lines) and risers (vertical lines) and form stairs over a sloped line. So far, I'm generating stairs, but for some reason with no respect to the sloped lines' height `End.Y - Start.Y` and angle. I want the stairs to be perfectly aligned to the sloped line with variable height, length, and angle. The easiest way to input it is through a `Line` struct with a start and end point.

```
public struct Line
{
    public Point Start, End;

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public int Length => (int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((End.Y - Start.Y), 2) + Math.Pow((End.X - Start.X), 2)); // The actual length of the sloped line.
    public float Angle => (float)Math.Atan((End.Y - Start.Y) / (End.X - Start.X)); // Calculate angle in degrees.
    public int Height => End.Y - Start.Y; // Available height for the stair.
}
```

Here is my attempt. I've documented everything within the comments, that should explain my situation.

```
    public static List<Line> GenerateStairs(Line sloped_line)
    {
        List<Line> list = new List<Line>();

        // What am I to do with the angle?
        double slopeAngleDegrees = sloped_line.Angle; // Slope angle in degrees
        double slopeAngleRadians = slopeAngleDegrees * Math.PI / 180; // In radians

        double totalLength = sloped_line.Length; // Total length of the sloped line
        double availableHeight = sloped_line.Height; // Total available height of the sloped line
        double treadDepth = 30; // Depth of each tread (Typically I want my treads to be near 30cm)
        double riserHeight = 20; // Height of each riser (And risers near 20cm)
        // Note that I'm working with a primitive staircase shape, only treads and risers.

        // Calculate the number of treads and risers
        int numberOfTreads = (int)Math.Floor(totalLength / treadDepth);
        int numberOfRisers = (int)Math.Floor(availableHeight / riserHeight);

        // Calculate the horizontal run for each tread
        double horizontalRun = totalLength / numberOfTreads;
        double verticalRun = availableHeight / numberOfRisers;
        // Getting horizontalRun/verticalRun from dividing tread/riser count by sloped angle (either degrees or radians) gives unwated results.

        // "Draw" the staircase
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTreads; i++)
        {
            // Calculate the X and Y coordinates for the start and end of each tread
            double startX = i * horizontalRun;
            double startY = i * verticalRun;
            double endX = (i + 1) * horizontalRun;
            double endY = (i + 1) * verticalRun;

            // Tread
            list.Add(new Line(new Point((int)startX, (int)startY), new Point((int)endX, (int)startY)));

            // Riser
            list.Add(new Line(new Point((int)endX, (int)startY), new Point((int)endX, (int)endY)));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Top left of the canvas is 0,0; Here are some of the results. The line starts at 0,0 and has a variable end point. The function calculates the height, sloped length, and angle in both degrees and radians. This is way too complicated than I thought, and I'm stuck here.

Red is the input line, and the stairs should be aligned over the line.

[image]

Height > Length

[image]

Length > Height

[image]

Almost perfect 45 angle, but still not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem: Using length of line to as width.

Second: You are always adding a riser and not using `numberOfRisers` which resulting similar stairs every time.

Actual solution depends on how you want to handle when ratio of riser height to tread width does not match line slope. i.e.: If you want to have same tread width try following.

```
    public static List<Line> GenerateStairs(Line sloped_line)
    {
        List<Line> list = new List<Line>();

        double totalLength = sloped_line.End.X - sloped_line.Start.X; // Total width of the sloped line
        double availableHeight = sloped_line.Height; // Total available height of the sloped line
        double treadDepth = 30; // Depth of each tread (Typically I want my treads to be near 30cm)
        double riserHeight = 20; // Height of each riser (And risers near 20cm)
        // Note that I'm working with a primitive staircase shape, only treads and risers.

        // Calculate the number of treads and risers
        int numberOfTreads = (int)Math.Floor(totalLength / treadDepth);

        // Calculate the horizontal run for each tread
        double horizontalRun = totalLength / numberOfTreads;
        double verticalRun = availableHeight / numberOfTreads;
        // Getting horizontalRun/verticalRun from dividing tread/riser count by sloped angle (either degrees or radians) gives unwated results.

        // "Draw" the staircase
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTreads; i++)
        {
            // Calculate the X and Y coordinates for the start and end of each tread
            double startX = i * horizontalRun;
            double startY = i * verticalRun;
            double endX = (i + 1) * horizontalRun;
            double endY = (i + 1) * verticalRun;

            // Tread
            list.Add(new Line(new Point((int)startX, (int)startY), new Point((int)endX, (int)startY)));

            // Riser
            list.Add(new Line(new Point((int)endX, (int)startY), new Point((int)endX, (int)endY)));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

I did not run it, there may be typos.

Comment: Amazing! Still a bit hard for me to grasp, but the riser height here isn't even needed, since I will mind my sloped line when constructing stairs. This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!